# Real-time load result (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know how write this script. I need load results with some URL (eg: localhost/index.php?action=get&type=29) and this result to give a variable for further processing. I need create this on Jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are features in jQuery that can be used, you have either a quick load using the simple [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function that will parse the HTML into an element. Usage:

```
$('#element').load('http://www.urlgoeshere.com/');
```

With processing events with AJAX with further writing options, you have many options to choose from:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

These options below are using the `.ajax()` function but makes the writing easier:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**EDIT:** With your "refresh", you can use the `setTimeout` function to repeat the ajax call:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "action=get&type=29",
        success: function(arg){
            // do something
        }
    });
}, 1000); // This will "refresh" every 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost/index.php",
    data: "action=get&type=29",
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
       // data is the response from the server, status is the http status code, 
       // xhr is the actual xhr
    },
    error: function(){
    },
    ...
});
```

to get the results.

Be sure to define the `success` and `error` callbacks to process the data when it is returned.

Look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "action=get&type=29",
    success: function(arg){
        // do something
    }
});
```